# Kafka Streams app fails to start with “what(): Resource temporarily unavailable” in Cloud Foundry

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, cloud-foundry, rocksdb

Dear Stackoverflowians,

I’m having a problem with a Spring Cloud Stream app using a Kafka Streams binder. It’s only in our own Pivotal Cloud Foundry (CF) environment where this issue occurs. I have kind of hit a wall at this point and so I turn to you and your wisdom!

When the application starts up I see the following error

```
<snip>
2019-08-07T15:17:58.36-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT     current active tasks: [0_3, 1_3, 2_3, 3_3, 4_3, 0_7, 1_7, 5_3, 2_7, 3_7, 4_7, 0_11, 1_11, 5_7, 2_11, 3_11, 4_11, 0_15, 1_15, 5_11, 2_15, 3_15, 4_15, 0_19, 1_19, 5_15, 2_19, 3_19, 4_19, 0_23, 1_23, 5_19, 2_23, 3_23, 4_23, 5_23]
2019-08-07T15:17:58.36-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT     current standby tasks: []
2019-08-07T15:17:58.36-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT     previous active tasks: []
2019-08-07T15:18:02.67-0700 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 2db4a719-53ee-4d4a-9573-fe958fae1b4f ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2019-08-07T15:18:02.64-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
2019-08-07T15:18:02.64-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR   what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
2019-08-07T15:18:02.67-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Stopping instance 516eca4f-ea73-4684-7e48-e43c
2019-08-07T15:18:02.67-0700 [CELL/SSHD/0]OUT Exit status 0
2019-08-07T15:18:02.71-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]OUT Exit status 134
2019-08-07T15:18:02.71-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Destroying container
2019-08-07T15:18:03.62-0700 [CELL/0]     OUT Successfully destroyed container
```

The key here being the line with
`what():  Resource temporarily unavailable`

The error is related to the number of partitions. If I set the partition count to 12 or less things work. If I double it, the process fails to start with this error.

This doesn’t happen on my local windows dev machine. It also doesn’t happen in my local docker environment when I wrap this app in a docker image and run. I can take the same image and push it to CF or push the app as a java app, I get this error.

Here is some information about the kafka streams app. We have an input topic with a number of partitions. The topic is the output of debezium connector and basically it’s a change log of a bunch of database tables. The topology is not super complex but it’s not trivial. Its job is to aggregate the table update information back into our aggregates. We end up with 17 local stores in the topology. I have a strong suspicion this issue has something to do with rocksdb and the resources available to the CF container the app is in. But I have not the faintest idea what the Resource is that’s “temporarily unavailable”.

As I mentioned, I tried deploying it as a docker container with various jdk8 jvms, different base images centos, debian, I tried various different CF java buildbacks, I tried limiting java heap with relation to max container memory size (thinking that maybe it has something to do with native memory allocation) to no avail.

I’ve also asked our ops folks to up some limits on the containers and open files limit changed from the initial 16k to now 500k+. I saw some file lock related errors as below but they went away after this change.

```
2019-08-01T15:46:23.69-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: lock : /home/vcap/tmp/kafka-streams/cms-cdc/0_7/rocksdb/input/LOCK: No locks available
2019-08-01T15:46:23.69-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR   at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method)
```

However the error `what():  Resource temporarily unavailable` with higher number of partitions persists.

ulimit -a on the container looks like this

```
~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1007531
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 524288
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I really do need to understand what the root of this error is. It’s hard to plan in this case not knowing what limit we’re hitting here.

Hope to hear your ideas. Thanks!

**Edit**:

Is there maybe some way to get more verbose error messages from the rocksdb library or a way to maybe build it so it outputs more info?

**Edit 2**

I have also tried to customize the rocksdb memory settings using `org.apache.kafka.streams.state.RocksDBConfigSetter`

The defaults are in `org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore#openDB(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext)`

First I made sure the Java heap settings were well below the container process size limit and left nothing to the memory calculator by setting
`JAVA_OPTS: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=100m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=145m -Xmx1000m`

With this I tried:

1.
Lowering the write buffer size
`org.rocksdb.Options#setWriteBufferSize(long)`
`org.rocksdb.Options#setMaxWriteBufferNumber(int)`

2.
Setting max_open_files to half the limit for the container (the total of all db instances)
`org.rocksdb.Options#setMaxOpenFiles(int)`

3.
I tried turning off the block cache altogether
`org.rocksdb.BlockBasedTableConfig#setNoBlockCache`

4.
I also tried setting cache_index_and_filter_blocks = true after re-enabling block cache
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Block-Cache#caching-index-and-filter-blocks

All to no avail. The above issue is still happening when I set higher number of partitions (24) on the input topic. Now that I have `RocksDBConfigSetter` with logging in it, I can see that the error happens exactly when the rocksdb is configured.

**Edit 3**

I still haven't gotten to the bottom of this. I have asked the question on https://www.facebook.com/groups/rocksdb.dev and was advised to trace system calls with strace or similar, but I was not able to obtain the required permissions to do that in our environment.

It has eaten up so much time that I had to settle for a workaround for now. What I ended up doing is refactored the topology to

1) minimize the number of materialized ktables (and the number of resulting rocksdb instances) and

2) break up the topology among multiple processes.

This allowed me to turn on and off topology parts in separate deployments with spring profiles and has given me some limited way forward for now.

Comment: Any chance that you are hitting this issue? https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/991

Comment: There is only the app deployed and nothing else. The rocksdb directories are on the container file system and there is only one java process. I don't think there are any overlapping processes accessing it. The lock error seemed to be specific to open files limit, but went away after changing it.

Comment: As you said, it looks like some configuration issues in rocksdb. Maybe you can tag rocksdb on this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the tag.

Comment: Hi @PawelZieminski, did you happen to fnid the issue? I'm currently experiencing a similar issue when migrating to a new version of OpenShift.

Comment: @JanBols this is nuts but I haven't solved that mystery yet. I added Edit 3 above with some more details. Definitely losing on points to kafka-streams right now, but I'll try to pick up this fight later and continue if I can. Try to use system call tracing if you can do it in your env. Do let me know if you find an answer, please!